# Azure Active Directory Groups Claim for Application

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, active-directory-group

We're using Active Directory Groups for different customers and their employees. It's straightforward configuring a group accessToken claim for authenticated users. Now, when an app does not act in behalf of a user but in behalf of itself (client_credentials flow), and the app is member in an AD Group, is it possible to configure an accessToken claim for the application's membership? If so, how?

I have tried to configure it in Azure/Active Directory/Token configuration but it gives only the group of users that are authenticated and not that of the app itself.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to configure group claims for application tokens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a problem with your description. You said in the question: **and the app is member in an AD Group**.  As far as I know, the members of a group can only be users, organization contacts, service leaders or other groups, and there is no application.

I think what you want to say is that you assigned users or groups to the application (please correct me if my understanding is wrong), like this:

[image]

As far as I know,  there is no group claim for application tokens(The user token has a group claim, as you said in the question),because  application is not a member of group.
If you want to get the group assigned to the application, MS graph api is a good choice:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/{id}/appRoleAssignedTo
```

You need to replace `{id}` with `Object ID`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the suggestion to use the graph API. It is possible to add applications (type service principals) to a user group.

Comment: @thomasuebi  Hi,  did this solve your problem?